# Copying data from Column to another sheet - VBA on Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a Workbook where a Main Sheet will feed from the info on 7 others.

Basically im trying to get some direction on this code i have written:

```
Private Sub UpdateSheet3_Click()
Dim PolicyNumber As String, InsuredName As String

Worksheets("Universal").Select
PolicyNumber = Worksheets("Universal").Cells(A4.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
InsuredName = Cells(B4.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
Worksheets("Carriers").Select
Worksheets("Carriers").Range("B2").Select
If Worksheets("Carriers").Range("A4").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
Worksheets("Carriers").Range("A4").End(xlDown).Select
End If
Worksheets("Carriers").Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.Value = PolicyNumber
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = InsuredName
Worksheets("Universal").Select
Worksheets("Universal").Range("A4:B4").ClearContents



End Sub
```

What im trying to do is that my button (which is on sheet "Carriers") copies the values of PolicyNumber from the sheet "Universal" starting from Cell A4 and down until a blank row appears.

This will be pasted into cell B2(or next empty row) from sheet "Carriers".

I have beginner knowledge in VBA, i will appreciate your help.

I have many other Columns that i want to also copy(i tried doing to on this code, InsuredName being the 2nd one) but if i can get thru the first column i can figure out the rest.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks! i have updated the question. apologies

Comment: some of your `.select` statements are just random clicking at various cells, without any purpose ... for instance the `if ... then` statement does nothing, because sometimes it select a cell, but the next instruction negates that selection.  .... using `select   ...  active` in your code will cause you grief. refer to cells directly instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to look through as many posts as possible or Google some tutorials because there are too many errors in your code.  I have come up something for you at least to get you going and not scare you but this will just doing basic copy for your need.

```
Private Sub UpdateSheet3_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim PolicyNumber As Integer
Dim InsuredName As Integer

Set ws1 = Sheets("Universal")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Carriers")

ws1.[A1].Select
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ws1.Range("A4:A" & lastRow).Copy ws2.Range("B1:B" & lastRow - 3)

End Sub
```

Comment: These gives me an error at:

ws1.[A1].Select

not sure why we selecting A1 there.

Comment: `[A1]` is a short version of `Range("A1")`.  You can try to change to `ws1.Range("A1").Select`.  But I didn't get any errors.  Also, I don't know which cell you want to point to.  You can always change this value to whichever cell that you'd like to use.

Comment: Awesome.  Don't forget to mark this as the answer so this can be closed.